# SharePoint 2010 Compatibility with Office 2013 on Client

Tags: office

Hi We have a web based SharePoint 2010 webapp and our client is upgrading their os with Office 2013. Would there be any compatibility issues when uploading and downloading document from Document library of our SharePoint app.

Do you guys foresee any concerns of any compatibility issues. Probably any new formats with aren't available with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar thread over on TechNet's forums.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9124f4f9-02e4-4997-a54c-da14e8069964/compatability-issues-with-sharepoint-2010-and-office-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral
From the sound of it, there shouldn't be any issues. Format is still .docx and any metadata contained in the xml that SP2010 doesn't recognize will just be ignored. Best way to be sure is to pilot it on a few machines, see how it goes, and if all is well, ship!

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any compatibility issues. There are some new integration features between Office 2013 and SharePoint 2013 which your SharePoint 2010 might not enjoy but they certainly won't impact on the functionality of your existing SharePoint 2010 Apps. I had never faced any issue while working with Office 2013 on client machines and SharePoint 2010 on server.

For a workaround, if you face any issues while opening office files in web browser, ensure you have IE 9 (32-bit) installed on your client machine.